# jquery onclick on input radio to show/hide input text

Tags: jquery, css, onclick

i'm trying to toggle(hide/show) an input text by radio button choice but it doesn't work.

What's wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/mwwj9vvt/
Thanks :-)

```
onclick="$('#idprezzoCSSClass').css('display', 'yes');"
```

---

I'm not understanding why problem is: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
Commenting and using diffrent jquery version/resource it works, but i need ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
https://jsfiddle.net/6psb8c73/

Comment: you need to use 'display','block'..there's no such property like 'yes'

Comment: You are mixing jQuery with pure JS

Comment: and this too...

Comment: onclick="$('#idprezzoCSSClass').css('display', '');"

Comment: Using "block" instead "yes" still doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Refer the code below, it might help you

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
});
</script>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
enter code here
```

Comment: It works only if i don't add [code]<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1"> 
 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>[/code]